# A searchbar has to display a result where each of it must contain all of the searched words, regardless of the order in which they were written?

Tags: swift, filter, uisearchbar

In Swift 5.3, in my searchbar, i want to display a result tableview where each of its cells must contain all of the searched words, regardless of the order in which they were written in the searchbar.

Example:
i have a struct of objects:

```
struct Object {
  var story : String
  var age: Int
  ...
}
```

my tableview display this array before the search:

```
Array  : [Object] =  [
              Object(story:"English texts for beginners to practice", age: 1200),
              Object(story:"reading and comprehension online", age: 1600),
              Object(story:"and for free. Practicing your comprehension", age: 1800),
              Object(story:"of written English will both improve", age: 1100),
              Object(story:"your vocabulary and comprehension", age: 1500),
              Object(story:"of grammar and word order." age: 1400)
             ]
```

And when i tap "comprehension your" in the searchbar, it will retrieves this filtered array:

```
filteredArray = [
              Object(story:"and for free. Practicing your comprehension", age: 1800),
              Object(story:"your vocabulary and comprehension", age: 1500)
              ]
```

And of course i have this function of UISearchBar

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
       if searchText.isEmpty {
               filteredArray = Array // To see all the Array

self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Here is what i have tried, but it's not what i need

```
if let searchBarText = searchBar.text{
                let searchText = searchBarText.lowercased()
                           filteredArray = Array.filter ({$0.story.lowercased().range(of: searchText.lowercased()) != nil})
                
                           filteredArray += Array.filter ({$0.story.lowercased().range(of: searchText.lowercased()) != nil})
                           tableView.reloadData()
               }
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes, i will write it in the end of my question,
all the word must figure in the filteredArray, regardless of their order

Comment: Transform `searchText` into an array of String (each word), and check that all of them are inside an `Object`. But if you write "your your", does it have to be twice in the search text or no?

Comment: no, if i write "your your" the result will consider only one "your"
But how could i transform searchText to an array of Strings? because search text is just a String !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Set of the given search words and then use `filter` where all the words in the search text are checked against the `story` using `allSatisfy`

```
let words = Set(searchText.split(separator: " ").map(String.init))
let filtered = array.filter { object in words.allSatisfy { word in object.story.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(word) } })
```